# PHPStorm path mappings for ZF2 sessionmanager

Tags: zend-framework2, xdebug, phpstorm

I'm attempting to troubleshoot PHPStorm and Xdebug on a ZF2 based project

- I setup XDebug 2.x properly
- Got PHPStorm to pickup the settings
- Set a few breakpoints down in my /public/index.php

.. success was mine.  But then I start to need to map the ZF2 related PHP files, and it's staying grayed out.

[image]

Comment: It is not necessary to map every single file (it would be stupid) -- you can create mapping for one of the parent folders and it will propagate to all children folders and files. So... 1) Please state the full path to that file on remote and local servers 2) Show all paths mappings you have got -- that screen but top part of it. P.S. Path mappings are done in `Settings | PHP | Servers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select menu `Run`->`Edit Configuration`

If you dont have any config `Add New Config`->`Php Web Application`

In bottom section `Before Lunch ...` click `Add`->`Upload Files To Remote Host`

`Local Roots to upload` is what you need , click add and select your `projects root directory` and then click `edit mapping` in the bottom ...

this should fix your mapping problem...

Comment: Im already hosting the files.. And the project is running browser fine.  Are you saying i should configure a remote host first, then redeploy in PHPstorm? Im developing locally on apache2.. Sounds like it.

Comment: no, you don't need to upload/deploy anything , you just need to have a configuration for you project that has mapping